Cannot call Blazor hosted API due to CSP
I've got the following API Controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
  private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

  public ItemsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  [HttpGet("Items")]
  public IEnumerable<Item> Get()
  {
    var items = _context.Items.ToArray();

    return items;
  }

  [HttpPost("Item")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateEmployee(Item item)
  {
    try
    {
        _context.Items.Add(item);

        var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (res > 0)
            return Ok();
        else return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            "Error updating data");
    }
  }
}

I can call the GET method from Firefox no problem but when I try to call the POST method I get an error about violating "default-src 'none'".
I have then added the following:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  context.Response.Headers.Append("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';");
  await next();
});

But now I get a non-expressive json+problem response and the code is not executed.
I do not know how to proceed from here.
Since I ultimately want to call this from a winforms app I've decided to go ahead and try that:
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
var res = client.UploadData("https://localhost:7250/api/Item", "Post", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

As in Firefox, the GET request works without issue but the POST request received an error "BAD REQUEST" with no further information.

Could you please share how you send the post request using another url's page by using ajax?

@BrandoZhang There is no ajax code as the client is a WinForms App. But I have added that.

The CSP error was a red herring.
The real problem was a non nullable navigation property on the entity framework model class.
Instead of:
class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Other> Others { get; set; } // non-nullable
}

It should say:
class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Other>? Others { get; set; } // nullable
}

It's unfortunate that blazor doesn't offer more a more helpful error message/response in such scenarios.

First of all, can you stop in debug mode on the breakpoint within UpdateEmployee method? If not I would suggest to explicitly mark item as the request body parameter usign attribute [FromBody]:
[HttpPost("Item")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateEmployee([FromBody] Item item) { 
    ... // can you stop here on the breakpoint?
}

If you can, try enforcing a Content Security Policy for ASP.NET Core Blazor by using a <meta> tag to apply the policy - check this out.
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="base-uri 'self';
               default-src 'self';
               img-src data: https:;
               object-src 'none';
               script-src 'self';
               style-src 'self';
               upgrade-insecure-requests;">


Thanks but I've figured it out in the meantime. Had nothing to do with CSP.
